# In Python I have two different files

Tags: python, function, import, return

In a Python code, I am trying to access a variable from a function in another file. The codes are:

**File1.py:**

```
S1 = [a,b,c,d,e]
S2 = [a,b,d,e]
def fc1(S1,S2):
    ...
    diag = S1 + S2
    return(diag)
```

**File2.py:**

```
from File1 import fc1,fc2
S1 = [a,b,c,d]
S2 = [a,b,d]
...
fc1(S1,S2)
print(diag)
...
```

However, it gives an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\File.py", line 102, in <module>
    print(diag):
NameError: name 'diag' is not defined
```

How can I access the `diag` variable from File2.py? I tried to assign as a global but it doesn't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you probably meant to assign the output of calling `fc1(...)`; the name `diag` is only defined in the function!

Comment: are `a,b,c,d` variables or strings? you never assign `diag` before using it.

Comment: You wanted `diag = fc1(S1,S2)`.  Names inside functions exist only in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first define 'diag' variable in File2.py:

```
diag = fc1(S1,S2)
```

and then print it:

```
print(diag)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined the `diag` variable in file2.py

try this:

```
from File1 import fc1,fc2
S1 = [a,b,c,d]
S2 = [a,b,d]
...
diag = fc1(S1,S2)
print(diag)
...
```